# How to analyze complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was reading a book on algorithms, there was such algorithm:

```
let differentCases = (arr:string[])=>{

 arr.forEach(x=>{
 
  console.log(x.toUpperCase())
  console.log(x.toLowerCase())


})
  
}
```

The book said the complexity of this algorithm was O(N), where N is the arr length. And said the inner functions (e.g. toUpperCase) each had complexity of O(1).

But I have such question.

If I had taken the  toUpperCase and analyzed it separately, It would have O(M) time complexity when M is the value of the string length, which we are trying to convert to upper case, right?

So why in the loop it was considered as O(1)?

Comment: Can you add more detail about this algorithm? I am assuming when analyzing the complexity of the given algorithm, the book seems to be simplifying by considering the `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` functions as constant-time operations, O(1) or `x` length is always constant, but this is just an assumption. We can comment on it only after seeing the exact wording.

Comment: You can freely choose, what variables you are analyzing for. Here, the array length and not the string length was chosen. Just to give you an example that another variable could have been considered: The console.log function could store the console data in a not well-suited data structure. If you append a new line, all the old lines have to be copied. For short initial console length C the console.log gets quadratic in N: O(N² * M), for long console.log you get O(N * C * M). It is just a matter of definition, what the variables are. One using complexity analysis should choose wisely.

Comment: One answer is not more or less correct than the other.

Comment: @Sebastian can you please explain what you mean here "For short initial console length C the console.log gets quadratic in N: O(N² * M), for long console.log you get O(N * C * M)". Why short and long console log matters in your analysis ?

Comment: I was just giving an example. If the console is implemented as inefficient buffer (which has to be resized, when copying), you suddenly get new variables, which matter. Another case is integer arithmetic, which is sometimes modeled with the digit size of the numbers, sometimes just as O(1). Still there is no right or wrong. One can choose the variables. If it is homework or a test, then it should be part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think the code you pasted has an error, this is how I image was in the book

```
let differentCases = (arr:string[])=>{
 arr.forEach(x=>{
  console.log(x.toUpperCase())
  console.log(x.toLowerCase())
 })
}
```

#### If I had taken the toUpperCase and analyzed it separately, It would have O(M) time complexity when M is the value of the string length, which we are trying to convert to upper case, right?

Yes definitely.

#### So why in the book it was considered as O(1)?

My only explanation here, is that the book is assuming that each string contained in `arr:string[]` has 1 single character. Or, as suggested by *anatolyg* in a the comment below , a constant length).

But I agree with you, without such precondition the Time Complexity of this code is `O(n) * O(m)` where `m` is the length of the longest string in `arr`.

```
let differentCases = (arr:string[])=>{
 arr.forEach(x=>{ // O(n)
  console.log(x.toUpperCase()) // O(m)
  console.log(x.toLowerCase()) // O(m)
 })
}
```

## An alternative approach

Given m = m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> + ... + m<sub>n</sub> where m<sub>i</sub> is the length of the `i-th` string in `arr`.

Then the time complexity can be expressed as

```
O(n) + O(m)
```

#### Why `O(n) + O(m)` instead of `O(m)`?

You cannot just consider O(m) because `n` might grow faster than `m`.

Why? Let's consider the corner case where `arr` contains 1 empty string.

Now:

- n = 1
- m = 0

That means: the algorithm will execute 1 time this block

```
console.log(x.toUpperCase()) 
console.log(x.toLowerCase())
```

Now let's consider the case where `arr` contains 2 empty strings.

Now:

- n = 2
- m = 0

That means: the algorithm will execute 2 times this block

```
console.log(x.toUpperCase()) 
console.log(x.toLowerCase())
```

In general, the number of times the body of the forEach is executes grows linearly with n.

So, even if m = 0 (in other words all the strings have length 0), the complexity of the algorithm still grows.

That's why the time complexity is O(n) + O(m)

Comment: Can you explain in detail why :  O(n) + O(m)  ? I think it should be O(m)

Comment: @user3257598 It depends on the meaning you give to m. What’s m in your case?

Comment: m = m1 + m2 + ... + mn

Comment: @user3257598 I have added this paragraph __Why O(n) + O(m) instead of O(m)?__ to explain why.

Comment: The book might have assumed the lengths of the strings are constant, e.g. less than 80 characters. This may be reasonable, depending on where the strings came from. But of course, if you look at the algorithm without any assumptions, your analysis is great.

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks, I have included your observation in the answer.